# keep getting a error not all code paths return a value on my pig Latin translator any advice on how to fix this?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace pig_laitn
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("please enter a sentence to be translated to pig latin");
            string sentence = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            string translated = Translator(sentence);

            
            Console.WriteLine(translated);
        }
         static Boolean IsVowel(char ch)
            {
                if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u')
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        private static string Translator(string sentence)
        {
            int pos = -1;
            char ch;

            List<string> translated = new List<string>();

            foreach (string word in sentence.Split(' '))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
                {
                    ch = word[i];

                    if (IsVowel(ch))
                    {
                        pos = i;

                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (pos == 0)
                {
                    translated.Add(word + "way");
                }
                else
                {
                    String a = word.Substring(pos);
                    String b = word.Substring(0, pos);
                    translated.Add(a + b + "ay");
                }
                return string.Join(" ", translated);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are missing a return at the end of the code after foreach loop.

Comment: If sentence is empty, there will be no return.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you meant to loop through *all* of the words in the sentence, not to return after processing the *first* word. Since you have a `return` statement *inside* of your loop block, it'll do the latter instead of the former. This also explains why not all code paths return, since if you do no iterations of the loop, no return statement will be hit.

Simply move your `return` statement so it's *after* your loop:

```
foreach (string word in sentence.Split(' '))
{
    // ...                
    // Do not return here, return after the loop.
}
return string.Join(" ", translated);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a return statement after your `foreach` loop:

```
      else
      {
         String a = word.Substring(pos);
         String b = word.Substring(0, pos);
         translated.Add(a + b + "ay");
      }

      return string.Join(" ", translated);
   }
    
   // ----> Missing return statement here <---
}
```

If I'm following your logic correctly, you actually intended to have the return statement after the loop itself, so just move the return statement down past the brace as seen in the code above.

Comment: lol i knew it was something stupid thank you for reminding me to check the scope i moved my return statment down and were all good